# JFrame não atualiza até função do botão terminar

Tags: java, swing

Quando eu clico no botão ele chama um método, e até esse método terminar a JFrame não atualiza

o programa está na imagem abaixo

[image: Programa]

```
private void jButtonBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
     jTextArea.setText("");
     AtualizeStats("Buscando Dispositivos");
     if (bioSignals.SearchDevice())
     {
         jButtonIniciar.setEnabled(true);
     }
 }
```

o método que realmente demora é o que está dentro da condição if, mas o que vem antes basicamente deveria aparecer instantaneamente, até porque o método AtualizeStats("Buscando Dispositivos") só muda o texto da caixa preta e printa no console:

```
public void AtualizeStats(String stats)
{
    System.out.println(stats);
    jTextArea.append(stats + "\n");
}
```

o que acontece é que no console aparece "Buscando Dispositivos" instantaneamente mas a JFrame espera até tudo o que está no listener do botão ser executado

Comment: E tá certo, tudo isso roda na mesma _thread_... Deve ter alguma coisa pra forçar a atualização da UI. Se esse tipo de coisa não for recorrente, dá pra usar algo assim.

Comment: Jovem, depois de `AtualizeStats("Buscando Dispositivos");` tente fazer `jTextArea.revalidate()` ou `repaint()`

Comment: nenhum dos dois funcionou, continua do mesmo jeito

Comment: o que eu acho mais estranho é que até o estado do botão fica travado, ele permanece clicado até terminar de executar

Comment: No site há exemplos de utilização do swingworker [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swingworker),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder executar tarefas sem travar a interface gráfica, você precisa utilizar a classe [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), pois ela foi feita para paralelizar tarefas demoradas da [**EDT**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), que é a thread que gerencia o funcionamento da interface gráfica no swing.

Dentro dessa classe, você irá delegar a tarefa no método `doInBackground()`, que roda num pool separado, de forma que a tela continua funcionando, enquanto a tarefa executa. É possível também exibir progresso com as classes `publish()` e `process()`, e exibir algum aviso de termino através da classe `done()`.

Não vou entrar nos detalhes de cada método pois não é o objetivo da resposta, mas deixarei alguns links para estudo no final. Segue um exemplo de uso do `SwingWorker`, semelhante ao que você está fazendo, há comentários em trechos relevantes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.List;

public class SwingWorkeSimpleExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel northPanel;
    private JButton btnSearch;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(SwingWorkeSimpleExample::new);
    }

    public SwingWorkeSimpleExample() {
        setTitle("SwingWorker Test");
        initComponents();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 300));
        this.contentPane = new JPanel();
        this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);

        this.northPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));
        this.contentPane.add(this.northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.btnSearch = new JButton("Search...");
        this.btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionWorker());
        this.northPanel.add(this.btnSearch);

        this.textArea = new JTextArea();
        this.textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.textArea);
        this.scrollPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 0, 2, 0));
        this.contentPane.add(this.scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 10);
        this.contentPane.add(this.progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void textAreaAppend(String str) {
        this.textArea.append(str + System.lineSeparator());
    }

    class ActionWorker implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    //aqui tudo ocorrerá em paralelo a gui
                    //desativo o botão, adiciono uma mensagem inicial
                    btnSearch.setEnabled(false);
                    textAreaAppend("Searching...");
                    //laço que alimenta a barra de progresso apenas para exemplo
                    for (int i = 0; i < progressBar.getMaximum(); i++) {

                        if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0)
                            textAreaAppend("Wait...");
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        //esse metodo "publica" atualizações da tarefa
                        //para a que a barra de progresso seja alimentada
                        //conforme o incremento do laço
                        publish(i);
                    }

                    textAreaAppend("Done!");
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                    //este métodor recebe o que foi "publicado"
                    // no doInBackground para que possamos atualizar
                    //o progresso na tela
                    progressBar.setValue(chunks.stream().reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0));
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    //entrará aqui quando terminar a tarefa, ou
                    //ocorrer alguma exceção
                    progressBar.setValue(0);
                    btnSearch.setEnabled(true);
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Executando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swingworker

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou muito bem