# Como atualizar JTextArea automaticamente

Tags: java

Criei um programa que tem um for, esse for gera diferentes valores, o que preciso é imprimir os valores em um `JTextArea` a medida que 8 valores são gerados. Fiz o seguinte:

```
int tp=2;
int pop[][] = new int[tp][8];

Random ran = new Random();
for(int i=0; i<tp; i++){
     String texto="";
     for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
           int valor = ran.nextInt(2);
           pop[i][j] = valor;
           texto += valor+", ";
     }
     txtArea.setText(txtArea.getText()+"\n"+"Valor: "+texto);
}
```

Teoricamente deveria ir setando o valor no `JTextArea`, mas isso não acontece.

Não sei como resolver esse problema.

Comment: O que é essa matriz `pop`?

Comment: Essa matriz é onde vou guardar os 8 valores, o numero de linhas dela é "tp" e o numero de coluna 8

Comment: Por favor, adicione um **[mcve]** pois esse código tem algumas variáveis que nem são mostradas seus tipos.

Comment: Se o objetivo é atualizar o componente ainda com o laço em execução, você precisará de SwingWorker. Veja um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248098/28595

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
int tp = 2;
int colunas = 8;
int pop[][] = new int[tp][colunas];

Random ran = new Random();
StringBuilder texto = new StringBuilder(tp * (colunas + 8));
for (int i = 0; i < tp; i++) {
     texto.append("Valor: ");
     for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
           int valor = ran.nextInt(2);
           pop[i][j] = valor;
           texto.append(valor);
     }
     texto.append('\n');
}
txtArea.setText(texto.toString());
```